# WSO2 - API Manager 2.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Need to compute IOPS required for SSD when using API Manager 2.1.0

When working with API and Key Manager databases, what should be the typical IOPS for the database SSD? We expect around 1000 HTTP POST requests Per Second. This needs to be authenticated and routed to one of the back-end Service end-points. Also, can anyone provide details on database queries that get executed when API requests are processed by the Worker Gateways? Are stored procedures used while accessing the API and Key Manager databases and what is the schema for the databases? Please provide any links that will help understand the low-level details of the database interactions.

Comment: Have you gone through the https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/WSO2+API-M+Performance+and+Capacity+Planning

Comment: Yes, I went through the document. There is reference to db.m3.medium but i do not know how many HTTP POST requests per second this will be capable of handling. We wanted to know the IOPS that we should use for the SSD (for APIM and Key Manager database) assuming the fact that the 1000 requests per second could be accessing 1000 different resources in the back-end system.